# Is it possible to get a marksman award with a shotgun?

Tags: battlefield-3

I've been trying to get a marksman award with the shotgun just for the pure "wtf" credit. So far I'm using frag rounds with the Saige 12K and a 7X scope.

Is it even possible though to get a marksman award with something that isn't a sniper rifle? I can get headshots with the shotgun, but it's extremely difficult getting 1 shot kills with headshot and a shotgun

Comment: In BC2 it could have been any weapon, but it had to be Recon class, probably hasn't changed.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be possible, although I think this video might have been made during the beta:

(Some NSFW language in the video)

He's using a scope + the slug ammunition type, and he gets the marksman award at the timecode I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a similar setup to agent86's video, and have been able to get marksman ribbons. The pump shotgun does more damage, and the slug ammo is needed for any sort of range. The 4x scope is my preferred optics for most engagements.

Here's my loadout:

- 870 MCS
- 12g Slug Ammo
- Extended Mag
- ACOG (4x)

The 870 also has a smaller cone of effect, so you're more likely to get the headshot if you're using buckshot.